# How to find the root of an adjective using Wordnet or any other NLP tool?

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

I need to stem words to get the root words. I was able to get the stemmed words for nouns and verbs but unable to get the root words of adjectives.

```
    WordnetStemmer stem =  new WordnetStemmer(ws.getDictionary());
    System.out.println("test" + stem.findStems("shooting",POS.VERB) );
    System.out.println("test" + stem.findStems("gunshots",POS.VERB) );
```

The following works but when I try it for an adjective it doesn't. Is there any way to stem an adjective or get the root form of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`WordnetStemmer`has been implemented as an extension of `SimpleStemmer`

So there is definitely a way to stem ADJECTIVES. If the stemmer doesn't find the word, it won't return any stems.

You have a couple of options:

1. When calling findStems, you can leave the POS as Null, in which case it will return stems for all parts of speech. See the documentation [here](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/api/edu/mit/jwi/morph/WordnetStemmer.html#findStems%28java.lang.String,%20edu.mit.jwi.item.POS%29)
2. Try calling `SimpleStemmer` instead. As you can see from the [Rules of Detachment](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/api/edu/mit/jwi/morph/SimpleStemmer.html), many Adjectives are handled, but there will still be a huge number of Adjectives that the `stemmer` won't handle.

A few samples of adjective stemming:

```
ADJ "er" ""
ADJ "est" ""
ADJ "er" "e"
ADJ "est" "e"
```

Hope that helps you move forward.